# El tipo "never" no tiene signaturas de llamada

Tags: reactjs

estoy haciendo un login con react y me encuentro con un problema, estoy usando `reactContext` para poder hacer el `logeo` del usuario y guardar algunas cosas mas, les dejo la configuracion de mi contexto:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import { GetToken, SetToken, DeleteToken } from './../helpers/auth-helpers'
import Axios from './../helpers/axios-helper'
const usuarioContext = React.createContext(undefined)
export const UsuarioProvider = (props: any) => {

  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState(null)
  const [cargandoUsuario, setCargandoUsuario] = useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{

    async function cargarUsuario() {
      if(!GetToken(1)){
        setCargandoUsuario(false);
        return;
      }
      try {
        const { data: usuario } = await Axios.get("/api/usuario")
        setUsuario(usuario)
        setCargandoUsuario(false)
      } catch (errors) {
        throw new Error(errors);
      }
    }

    cargarUsuario()

  },[])

  const login: any = async (value: any) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post("/api/iniciar", value)
      setUsuario(data.usuario)
      SetToken("token", data.token)
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }

  const signup = async (usuario: any) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post("/api/registrar", usuario)
      setUsuario(data.usaurio)
      SetToken("token", data.token)
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }

  const logout = () => {
    setUsuario(null)
    DeleteToken("token")
  }

  const value = useMemo(()=>{
    return ({
      usuario,
      cargandoUsuario,
      signup,
      login,
      logout
    })
  },[usuario, cargandoUsuario])

  return <usuarioContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

export const useUsuario = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(usuarioContext)
  if(!context){
    throw new Error("useUsuario debe estar dentro del provedor");
  }
  return context
}
```

primero que nada, quiero agregar una duda, es la primera vez que creo un contexto con typescript, cuando creo el contexto en js no me da ninguna advertencia, pero aqui en typescript me dice que no se proporcionó ningún argumento para `defaultValue`, yo coloque `undefined`, no se si estara bien, esa es mi primer duda, y la verdadera razon por la que hago esta pregunta es que cuando quiero usar la funcion `login` del contexto, esta me dice que no puedo llamar a esa expresion por que el tipo "never" no tiene signaturas de llamada